# How to import module with ambiguous name from PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, import, module, python-2.x, ambiguous

I am doing

```
sys.path.append(dst)
```

where `dst` contains `common.py` and want to import it. Unfortunately, I already have `common` module with another code. Is there a way to solve ambiguity?

---

More exact question is how to allow premade module, which imports module of ambiguous name (`import common`) to work inside premade context, which already has another module with the same name (`common`).

Comment: You could make `dst` a package and then `from dst import common`

Comment: Having two modules with the same name is not a good idea. Can't you rename one of them?

Comment: `from dst import common as dstcommon`?